# C# MVC 5 - Ajax - Executar duas Action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Bom dia.

Gostaria de executar duas Action, um que exibe o resultado na tela e o outro que gera um arquivo excel.

A View que exibe os resultado no seu topo tem o botão de pesquisa e um checkbox para saber se quer gerar o arquivo em excel. Então, criei um código via ajax para tentar executar as duas action (a action que exibe o resultado, fornece os dados para a action que gera o arquivo excel via TempData). Ou seja, se estiver marcado o checkbox ele executa a Action de exibição e depois chama a Action que gera o excel.
Porém ao usar o **event.preventDefault();** no click do botão, só exibe os resultados e sem o **event.preventDefault();** só realiza o download.

**View**

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#btnPesquisar").click(function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            $("#loaderDiv").show();



            var myformdata = $("#formPesquisar").serialize();


            var partes = myformdata.split('&');
            
            partes.forEach(function (parte){
                var chaveValor = parte.split('=');
                var chave = chaveValor[0];
                var valor = chaveValor[1];
                if (chave == 'excel') {
                    if (valor == 'true') {
                        gerarExcel = true;
                    }
                }
            })

            



            $.ajax({


                type: "GET",

                url: "/Relatorios/Alunos",

                data: myformdata,

                success: function () {
                    $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                    if (gerarExcel == true) {
                        window.location = "/Relatorios/GerarArquivoExcel";
                    }

                },
                error: function (erro) {
                    alert("Erro: " + erro);
                },

                complete: function () {
                    gerarExcel = false;
                }
            })
        })

    })
</script>
```

**Action (exibir resultados)**

```js
        public ActionResult ALunos(bool excel = false)
        {
            List<Alunos> ListaAlunos = new List<Alunos>();


            var resultado = _context.Alunos.Where(a => a.Ativo==true);
            Thread.Sleep(1500);

            if (excel != false)
            {

                if (excel == true && Alunos.Count > 0)
                {
                    TempData["planilha"] = Util.Funcoes.GerarArquivoExcel(Alunos);
                    TempData["nomeArquivo"] = "ListaAlunos.xlsx";
                }
            }

            return (View(Alunos));
        }
```

**Action(Exportar Excel)**

```js
        public FileResult GerarArquivoExcel()
        {
            byte[] planilhaByte = TempData["planilha"] as byte[];
            string nomeArquivo = TempData["nomeArquivo"] as string;
            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            Stream planilhaStream = new MemoryStream(planilhaByte);
            return File(planilhaStream, contentType, nomeArquivo);
        }
```

Comment: e se você abrir o download em uma nova aba?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, continua a mesma coisa. Se tivesse uma solução para substituir o **event.preventDefault();**, provavelmente, funcionaria. Pois com ele só consigo fazer o download, sem ele só consigo exibir o retorno. Mas nunca os 2.

Comment: Eu me referia ao invés de você fazer um redirect com o `window.location`, atualizar o conteúdo da página atual e fazer um `window.open` para baixar o arquivo.

Comment: Já fiz isso @LeandroAngelo e o problema continua.